# Rasterize QML SVG Image in Alpha8 format

Tags: image, qt, memory, svg, qml

Importing a set of 80 icons in QML as non-visible images to be used for shader sources (for arbitrary colorization):

```
  property Image action: Image { sourceSize.width: 512; sourceSize.height: 512; source: "icons/action.svg"; mipmap: true; antialiasing: true }
  // 79 more of those
```

I discover that my memory consumption has skyrocketed, from 45 mb to 128 mb, a whooping ~185% increase, thats 83 extra mb for the 80 icons.

It was expected, after all, `512 * 512 * 4 / 1024 / 1024` makes up for exactly 1 mb of memory. However, that cost is not acceptable, especially in the face of targeting mobile phones with the app.

I could reduce the rasterization size, however, I want the icons to be nice and crisp. The icon size itself varies according to the device display, but for optimal user experience it needs to be about an inch or so. Given that most new high end phones are already pushing above 500 dpi, I'd really hate to scale the icons down and have them appear blurry.

Since the SVGs are supposed to be colorized in arbitrary colors, they are in effect simply alpha masks, meaning that all I really need is one of those 4 channels. Unfortunately, QML's `Image` doesn't seem to offer any sort of control, the SVG is rasterized to a RGBA image.

And indeed, if I

```
  QVector<QImage> imgs;
  imgs.reserve(80);
  QDirIterator it(":/icons", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
  while (it.hasNext()) {
      QSvgRenderer renderer (it.next());
      QImage ic(512, 512, QImage::Format_Alpha8);
      ic.fill(Qt::transparent);
      QPainter pp(&ic);
      renderer.render(&pp);
      imgs.append(ic);
  }
```

I get the expected modest 20 mb increase in memory usage.

Any ideas how to save on some memory?

Comment: If you don't need to be able to changing display sizes you could do that in C++ and cache the resulting images/bitmaps. Depending on platform this might even be possible at install time

Comment: The images were needed for a qml `ShaderEffect`, I haven't tested if it works with `QImage` directly, but I'd be surprised if it does given qml's design decisions and the lack of built in interopability between qml's `Image` and `QImage`.

Comment: Interesting, I would have assumed that it works given that `QImage` is the main C++ type for pixel data images and as such used by the QQuick `Image` element as well.

Comment: @KevinKrammer - `QImage` worked with QML in qtquick1, but that was removed in qtquick2, now you need to roll out your own image provider to get the interop.

Comment: I am not sure QtQuick1 had ShaderEffect, I thought that was new in QtQuick2. Or do you mean the `Image` element? It uses `QImage` IO infrastructure internally and yes you can use an image provider to provide images loaded elsewhere via custom URLs. Not necessary in case of cached images as one could simply use each image's file URI of course.

Answer (score 1):

2 hours later - good news, first and foremost, a custom `QQuickImageProvider` works out of the box with `QImage::Format_Alpha8`, no problems there. Unnecessary channels are eliminated.

But more importantly, I realized that the icons lend themselves very well to distance fields representation. So I now employ 128x128 SDF textures, which scale beautifully to far above 512x512, reducing the memory usage for the icons to the measly 1.25 mb, for a total of 64x reduction of ram usage compared to the initial implementation.

The only downside is the 3-4 seconds (on a Note 3 phone) additional startup, because the distance fields are calculated on startup, but there are remedies for this as well, I might switch to pre-computed SDFs or offload if to shaders, which would be a little more complex, but should reduce the time at least 5-fold.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the Image component is it appears to render the SVG to a bitmap before it is drawn. Hence the requirement to set sourceSize to force it to render your SVG at different resolutions. This force rendering can lead to poor memory usage and poor performance.

As an alternative, I found a number of components in QML that render SVG perfectly via the icon property.

```
Item {
    width: 256
    height: 256
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Item { }
        icon.source: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/biking-32.svg"
        icon.width: 256
        icon.height: 256
        icon.color: "blue"
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

Which renders my biking-32.svg at 256x256 resolution in blue:

[image: biking-32.svg rendered at 256x256 in blue]