# Hide/display part of an SVG file with QML

Tags: qt, svg, qml

My designer provides me `SVG` files for the conception of our HMIs and we've been wondering how to optimize the rendering of these images. He would like to avoid producing tons of `SVG` files that almost look the same.

Let's take this Wi-Fi icon as an example:

[image]

Instead of having 3 `SVG` files to display the whole range of Wi-Fi reception, we would like to display or hide each bar using one `SVG` file. Is that possible with `QML`?

Technically we were thinking of amending the `XML` code and reloading the file. Does that sound doable from a `QML` point of view?

Should we use masks?

EDIT: I've just found the [QSVGRenderer](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsvgrenderer.html#details) class. Since I'm getting the Wi-Fi power value from my model in `C++`, I could maybe take advantage of my backend to amend the `XML` content of the `SVG` file and reload it?

Comment: Good question. If bars would have a simpler pattern, say rectangles, it would be easy, however with such curved lines...

Comment: I'd say you are getting caught up in premature optimizations. Did you already establish you have a problem before rushing to add complexity to address it? Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821020/rasterize-qml-svg-image-in-alpha8-format/40822538#40822538

Comment: Well the current solution works. As I said it's more of a human problem, as our HMIs could receive numerous updates and we only have one designer to address all these changes.

Comment: It is far easier to address the issue on the graphics design side. The icon in question is made of 3 elements, and a designer can export 3 images out of it, gradually revealing the full icon. Then you have a concrete icon for every case, which is much simpler than incorporating additional programming logic to do extra trickery on a per-icon basis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [OpacityMask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) from  Qt Graphical Effects

Answer (score 0):

I concur with *dtech*'s commet.

Also be aware that `SVG` rendering is not the thing where Qt is performing best. If you don't need it in thousands of sizes, consider using no vector-based graphic-formats.

If your desire is, to have everything in one file, you might try to tweak [`Sprite`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-sprite.html)  or [`AnimatedImage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html) to select the correct "frame" from one Image in which you have all variations.

I have can not try it currently, but `Sprite` might be able to handle SVGs, too.